# Get Mouse position in Windows Phone App (ManipulationDelta)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, mouse

**I just want to have the relative mouse / finger position in Silverlight Windows Phone App**.

Using the original Silverlight Framework does not work because `MouseMove` does not update proper. 'MouseMove' event is firing very less instead of 'Manipulation' event. By using the `DeltaManipulation` event all works fast, but I am not able to calculate the position, relative to the device screen.

**Example:**

If user taps in the middle of the screen (Width/Height = 800/480), I want to see position 400,240. But `ManipulationOrigin` shows 0,0

```
Private Sub PageEditor_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaEventArgs) Handles Me.ManipulationDelta
    Call DragItem(e.ManipulationOrigin)' > e.ManipulationOrigin is 0,0 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tries of XNA and Silverlight methods, this one can show the Position of Mouse and it will show the position relative to any Framework Element too with high performance:

```
Private Touch As System.Windows.Input.Touch
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler System.Windows.Input.Touch.FrameReported, AddressOf Touch_FrameReported
End Sub


Private Sub Touch_FrameReported(sender As Object, e As TouchFrameEventArgs) 
    If Me.DragElement IsNot Nothing Then
        _MousePosition = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(Me.ucGameCanvas1).Position ' will return 400,240 as needed if user press in the middle of the screen
    End If
End Sub
```